# Identify & Set Current Project in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have two projects in the same solution that share a lot of files so it's hard to know which is the current project. I know I can go to the Solution explorer, but that takes too long to navigate back to the project.

Is there any way to identify and set the current project on Visual Studio 2010?   I'd prefer something like a dropdown list on the standard toolbar.

I know I can use the Solution explorer, but that takes too long to navigate to the project root.

Comment: What do you mean by "current project"? And what do you mean then by "know which is the current project"?

Comment: VS maintains a state variable for current project.  It is the project that shows up in the 2nd section of the build menu.  It is also the project that is searched if you do a Find and select "current project".

Comment: OK, and what do you mean by "knowing which is the current...", then? Beyond just opening up the Build menu.

Comment: I'd like to see the name of the current project in a drop down box on the standard tool bar, much like there is a drop down for the current configuration.  That way I could glance at the current project and set it quickly